# Android layout scaling

Tags: android, android-layout, scale, android-screen-support

If you set your target SDK version in the Android manifest file to "3", then your layout on large-screen devices will be just a scaled up version of what it is on small-screen devices. Once you set the target SDK to a higher SDK, you can create separate layouts for each screen density, which provides a much better user experience.

**However**, my layout is mainly made up of images, that are high enough resolution that they display just fine on all screen sizes, even when scaled up, because they're big enough that they don't need to be stretched. Now, it would be much easier for me to just create a small-screen layout and have it scaled up, because it would still look nice on large screens. Is there any way I can get that effect without going back to API level 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use weight parameter.
“weight” is a term that's used to specify how much of the screen a particular view should occupy if there’s any room left after it’s drawn.

Simply make a `LinearLayout` and place two `TextViews` within it as such:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="small"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:background="#123" />
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:text="huge"
    android:background="#456"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

You will notice how views occupy space accordingly. You can create any layout you want for smaller screen and specify weight attribute and every thing will be adjusted beautifully

Comment: Also make sure that you don't have layouts that would override the layout that you wanted ie. there is the layout folder (wanted) but if you have a layout-xlarge folder with a layout that has the same name the compiler in real time will choose the one from the layout-xlarge folder on xlarge screens (10" tablets)

Comment: This works for positioning views, but let's say I want scale things like border-widths which are set in `dp`. The actual `TextView` will scale according to the screen size, but the border-widget and the text size (and anything else set in `dp`) will be out of proportion depending on the screen size.

Comment: @Not Me Well here is this very useful link on layout designing. It will give you some idea about how android framework helps solving screen size issues.
http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/26/android-design-tips/

Comment: I'm a relatively experienced Android developer, and I understand layouts and how Android UIs work. It's just a pain in the neck to have to make the layouts scale (like I normally do) when I have absolutely no reason to (because the phone UI looks perfectly fine on tablets). In this case it's a lot more complex, because everything has to be aligned very precisely (to the pixel) for my requirements, so it's very hard to have to scale everything for each screen density.

Answer (score 4):

Just don't specify a layout for larger screens. By default it uses the same one for all screens unless a more specific layout is available. If you're using `match_parent` for the width and height and the images to `scaleType="fitCenter"` or `"centerCrop"` -- things like that, it should fill whatever screen size that it is run on.

Answer (score 2):

Dont'f forget making your app compaible with tablets. You must add

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

in your app manifest.

Comment: Pretty sure that by default all that is true.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. I thought Android already did this as long as you aren't using something like AbsoluteLayout. There's a few tricks that can help with the transition. Not entirely sure what the question is asking, but I'll give it a shot. Does API level 3 scale with aspect ratio or something?

I found that most of the UI ugliness going from phone to tablet deals with width. There's logic you can put in to fix the width at a certain res. Otherwise, the layout looks and acts fine. There other tricks like having assets sized using different dimens.xml, and having different sets of dimens.xml for different screen sizes and densities.

You don't have to have every single dimension in each version. You just have to have the base version of each value set, and you can set the different dimension in the other files.

Answer (score -1):

Only way to resize images through different screen size is to use nine patch. Here is more resource on that subject : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

I believe this is only thing that you can do is in layout use relative width/height (weight) and images formatted in ninepath.